# How to find last activity from which current activity is opened in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have one activity which can be open from more 4 or 5 different activity so i can find from which activity my current activity is called...

If any idea please help me..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You might want to add extras to the intent you use to start the activity to indicate where the intent is coming from or what the request is.

For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("caller", "MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

and then your `OtherActivity` could detect the "caller" in its `onCreate`:

```
String caller     = getIntent().getStringExtra("caller");
Class callerClass = Class.forName(caller);
```

Comment: I have used like this  Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("caller", getIntent().getComponent().getClassName());
startActivity(intent);

Comment: and then in other activity i have use String className = getIntent().getStringExtra("Caller") and then Class c = Class.forName(className); so i can use that as my destination activity

Answer (score 15):

Android has a function for it, if you use startActivityForResult:

> ComponentName prev = this.getCallingActivity();

Comment: `getCallingActivity()` method will only work when you have started the child activity as a `startActivityForResult`. If you will start the child activity as a normal was ie. using `startActivity()` then `getCallingActivity()` method will return null. This is mentioned in the [Android documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity()).

Answer (score 2):

Put some extras to intent for the different- different activities

eg:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, otherActivity.class).putExtra("from" , "previousActivity"));
```

and get extras in the current activity as

```
string act = getIntent().getStringExtra("from");
```

so "act" will indicate you the calling Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Create an Interfare And put Values for your Activities Then pass these Values in Intent And get in Child Activity take a look at this piece of code

```
public interface ActivityRefs {
            public static final int ACTIVITY_1 = 1;
            public static final int ACTIVITY_2 = 2;
            public static final int ACTIVITY_3 = 3;
}
```

Create Intent and pass value like this in Calling activity

```
intent.putExtra("callingActivity", ActivityRefs.ACTIVITY_1);
```

Then in Called activity

```
int callingActivityName = getIntent().getIntExtra("callingActivity", 0);

        switch (callingActivityName) {
        case ActivityConstants.ACTIVITY_1:
            // Activity3 is started from Activity1
            break;
        case ActivityConstants.ACTIVITY_2:
            // Activity3 is started from Activity2
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it, in my case we are on `ActivityA` to `ActivityB` then want to go back to `ActivityA` programmatically, here my code

ActivityA :

```
String currentActivity;
void onCreate(...){
...
currentActivity = this.getClass().getName();
...
}
```

Then on your intent (still in `ActivityA`) :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.putExtra("from", currentActivity);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

Now on ActivityB:

```
Class fromClass;
void onCreate(...){
...
String String from = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("from");
try {
    fromClass = Class.forName(from);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
...
}
```

Then on your intent(still in `ActivityB`) for back to `ActivityA`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, fromClass);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```