# How get name parent activity in child activity

Tags: android

How I can get name of parent activity in child activity. I have two activities where I can start the same activity. For better understanding: I have activity ONE, TWO, THREE. From activity ONE I can start activity THREE and from activity TWO I can start activity THREE. Now I have a question. How I can get in activity THREE, name of parent activity.So when I start activity THREE from activity ONE how I can get this information. I want to implement simple loop `if()` where I add objects to the ArrayList due to which activity starts my activity THREE. How I can do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410295/finish-parent-and-current-activity-in-android

Comment: If you are using the `android:parentActivityName` attribute in the manifest, then this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38088425/1617737 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this

FirstActivity:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra(Consts.PARENT_ACTIVITY_NAME, "ONE");
     ...
     startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity:

```
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     String parentName = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.EPARENT_ACTIVITY_NAME;
     if(parentName.equals(...)){ 
        ....
     }
```

But in my opinion it is better not to use the names of the activities. Later you'll want to change the name of the class, add new, etc. You will have to make a lot of edits and the code is hard to maintain. It is better to enter the mode of operation, and all other activity will cause your activity to a specific mode.
So:

FirstActivity:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra(Consts.PARENT_ACTIVITY_MODE, TwoActivity.MODE_EDIT);
     ...
     startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra(Consts.PARENT_ACTIVITY_MODE, TwoActivity.MODE_DELETE);
     ...
     startActivity(intent);
```

ThirdActivity:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra(Consts.PARENT_ACTIVITY_MODE, TwoActivity.MODE_COPY);
     ...
     startActivity(intent);
```

Some activity:

```
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     int mode = intent.getIntExtra(Consts.EPARENT_ACTIVITY_MODE);
     switch(mode){
         case MODE_EDIT:
              ....
              break;
         case MODE_DELETE:
              ....
              break;
         case MODE_COPY:
              ....
              break;
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should put an extra to the intent that is starting up that THREE activity.

```
intent.putExtra("prevActivity", "ONE");
```

When reading do this:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("prevActivity");
```

Answer (score 2):

one easy way to do it would be to add an context element to your intent and passing name of the activity

```
Intent in = new Intent(One.this, Three.class);
in.putExtra("activity", "One");
startActivity(in);
```

and then in `Three` Activity

```
this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("activity");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just passs a recognizable piece of data in the intent...

Answer (score 1):

Put your Actvity name in **Intent** and pass it... but never try to Use it to **update UI** or something since its in Paused state.. It will throw Exception..

Answer (score 0):

You can Complete your task by Creating an `Interface` as [Discused here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467922/how-to-find-last-activity-from-which-current-activity-is-opened-in-android/38093158#38093158) or you can do the job by putExtra as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("PARENT_ACTIVITY_NAME", "ThisActivityName");
     startActivity(intent);
```

And then receive in child like

```
String parentActivityName = intent.getStringExtra("PARENT_ACTIVITY_NAME");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `getIntent().getClass().getName()` to fetch it.