# How can I find an of activity the current activity is started from (startActivity)?

Tags: android

I have 3 activities. When I go from one activity to another by `startActivity`, how can I know in the activity I start, what's the activity it's started from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get name parent activity in child activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885994/how-get-name-parent-activity-in-child-activity)

Answer (score 1):

Just use intent and specify the parent activity like this :

Activity A will open Activity B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("parent_activity", "activityA");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in Activity B, check if the bundle contains `parent_activity` key

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        if (getIntent()!= null && getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("parent_activity")) {
            String parentActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra()("parent_activity");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You meant to use `getIntent()` and not `savedInstanceState` when looking up the `parent_activity` right?

Comment: Thanks George, I just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can put parent activity's identifier into the intent you're going to start and on the child activity access it.

**ParentActivity**

```
static final int ACTIVITY_CODE = 1;
...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY_CODE, ACTIVITY_CODE);
startActivity(intent);
...
```

**ChildActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int code = getIntent.getIntExtra(KEY_CODE)
    swith(code) {
    //do something
    }
}
```

We use an integer for key instead of activity name in case you change the name of your activity you'll have less trouble.

[How get name parent activity in child activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885994/how-get-name-parent-activity-in-child-activity?answertab=active#tab-top)