# Android - How to get parentActivityName attribute value programmatically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-manifest, android-toolbar

An activity is declared in my manifest like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".TicketingHomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ticketing_home"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity" />
```

How can I get the value of `android:parentActivityName` programmatically?

I need to do this as I have just replaced my ActionBar with a Toolbar, but `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)` is now showing the Up arrow in an activity even when there is no parentActivityName attribute set in the manifest. Therefore, I would like to detect in my BaseActivity if no parentActivityName has been set, so I can hide the Up arrow accordingly.

NB - This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885994/how-get-name-parent-activity-in-child-activity) as I am specifically asking how to detect the value of the `android:parentActivityName` attribute programmatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get name parent activity in child activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885994/how-get-name-parent-activity-in-child-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getParentActivityIntent()` on your BaseActivity.

It will return an Intent. Then you can call `getComponent()` that will return a `ComponentName` from where you can obtain the `android:parentActivityName` (classname).

**EDIT**

Code example:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {

        toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

        Intent parentActivityIntent = getParentActivityIntent();
        boolean doesParentActivityExist;
        if (parentActivityIntent == null) {
            doesParentActivityExist = false;
        }
        else {
            ComponentName componentName = parentActivityIntent.getComponent();
            doesParentActivityExist = (componentName.getClassName() != null);
        }
        //toolbar.setSubtitle("Has parent: " + doesParentActivityExist);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null && doesParentActivityExist) {

            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(doesParentActivityExist);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(doesParentActivityExist);

            actionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(doesParentActivityExist);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(doesParentActivityExist);

        }
    }
```