# How to know which activity has invoked current activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities, say A, B and C. How can I identify that Activity C is called from Activity A or activity B.

Answer (score 4):

Put an extra on the `Intent` that indicates where it originated from.

Comment: Just to add some code, you could check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467922/how-to-find-last-activity-from-which-current-activity-is-opened-in-android

Comment: already i am passing bundle through putExtras().

Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: @PC: So? Then add something to the `Bundle` that identifies who is starting Activity C.

Comment: Bundle contains the String[] of selected items from activity B to activity C.

Answer (score 0):

Send extras to intent stating which activity has launched it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, C.class);
intent.putExtra("FROMACTIVITY", "A");
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
intent.putExtra("FROMACTIVITY", "B");
startActivity(intent);
```

And in Activity C check the value

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getStringExtra("FROMACTIVITY");
```